# Mule jms consumers are picking message slowly

Tags: activemq-classic, mule-component, mule-esb

I m implementing mule ESB 3.9 to consume messages from active mq.

I have around 15 domain components to which it actually orchestrates to reach the final destination

I have configured a connection pool for jms and am using numberofconsumers as 32 and maximum thread in reciever as 500.

But what I see is until 4 messages per second the requests sent by jmeter is fine. But if I increase to 5 msgs per second then I find the request sent by jms averages to around 3 msgs per second slowly..

Any thought on how to configure the number of consumers and reciever thread ?

My target is 10 messages per second and also all my 15 components takes only 30 milli seconds each at max to process .so processing time by those components is good...yet I see the total throughput is around 3 seconds at times and mostly its because messages  are not being picked immediately.

Please suggest

Activemq xml

---

```html
<destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
                <policyEntry topic=">" >
                    <!-- The constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy is used to prevent
                         slow topic consumers to block producers and affect other consumers
                         by limiting the number of messages that are retained
                         For more information, see:

                         http://activemq.apache.org/slow-consumer-handling.html

                    -->
                                                                                
                                                                                                
                  <pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                    <constantPendingMessageLimitStrategy limit="10000"/>
                  </pendingMessageLimitStrategy>
                                                                  
                                                                                <slowConsumerStrategy>
                                                                                                <abortSlowConsumerStrategy/>
                                                                                  </slowConsumerStrategy>
                                                                                </policyEntry>
                                                                
                                                                
                                                                                <!--Mahesh added start-->
                                                
                                
                                                                                                <policyEntry queue=">" >
                                                                                                                  <slowConsumerStrategy>
                                                                                                                                <abortSlowConsumerStrategy/>
                                                                                                                  </slowConsumerStrategy>
                                                                                                </policyEntry>
                                
                                <!--Mahesh added end-->
                                
                                
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>

 <managementContext>
            <managementContext createConnector="false"/>
        </managementContext>
        
         <systemUsage>
            <systemUsage>
                <memoryUsage>
                    <memoryUsage percentOfJvmHeap="90" />
                </memoryUsage>
                <storeUsage>
                    <storeUsage limit="5 gb"/>
                </storeUsage>
                <tempUsage>
                    <tempUsage limit="5 gb"/>
                </tempUsage>
            </systemUsage>
        </systemUsage>
        
           <transportConnectors>
            <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
            <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        </transportConnectors>
```

Other information on Mule ESB

1. I am using a prefetch of 1 message
2. No of consumers are 32 and receiver threads are 500

mule-config ---->

```html
<spring:beans>
 <context:component-scan  base-package="com.test.esb.orm.db" />
 <spring:import resource="classpath*:applicationContext.xml" />
 <spring:import resource="classpath*:test-orm-beans.xml" />
 <spring:import resource="mule-domain-spring.xml"/>
</spring:beans>

<db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration" 
     dataSource-ref="testDataSource"
     doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
     
<db:generic-config name="Generic_TrackTraceDatabase_Configuration" 
     dataSource-ref="testTrackTraceDataSource"
     doc:name="Generic Database Configuration for Track Trace"/>
     
<!-- ********************* ESB Gateway Configurations ******************************** -->
<http:listener-config name="test-Shared-http-listener" host="${domain.gateway.host}" port="${domain.gateway.port}" doc:name="HTTP Listener connector for ESB Gateway (From ui)">
 <http:worker-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="64"
      poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"
      threadWaitTimeout="30000" />
</http:listener-config>

   
<jms:activemq-connector name="com.test.esb.trans.jmsConnector"
                                            username="${domain.amq.user.id}" password="${domain.amq.user.password}"
                                            connectionFactory-ref="pooledConnectionFactory"
                                            numberOfConsumers="16" acknowledgementMode="AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE"

                                            validateConnections="true"
                                            persistentDelivery="true"
                                            doc:name="AMQ Connector For Domain Routing Services"
                                            specification="1.1">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="500" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
    <dispatcher-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="500" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
    <reconnect count="15" frequency="5000" blocking="true"/>
</jms:activemq-connector>


    <jms:activemq-connector name="com.test.esb.domain.jmsConnector" 
      username="${domain.amq.user.id}" password="${domain.amq.user.password}" 
     connectionFactory-ref="pooledConnectionFactory"
     numberOfConsumers="16" acknowledgementMode="AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE"  
     
      validateConnections="true" 
      persistentDelivery="false" 
      doc:name="AMQ Connector For Domain Routing Services" 
      specification="1.1">
 <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="500" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
 <dispatcher-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="500" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
 <reconnect count="15" frequency="5000" blocking="true"/>
</jms:activemq-connector>

  
<jms:activemq-connector name="com.test.esb.domain.orchestrator.jmsConnector"
                                            username="${domain.amq.user.id}" password="${domain.amq.user.password}"
                                            connectionFactory-ref="pooledConnectionFactory"
                                            numberOfConsumers="16" acknowledgementMode="AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE"

                                            validateConnections="true"
                                            persistentDelivery="true"
                                            doc:name="AMQ Connector For Domain Routing Services"
                                            specification="1.1">
    <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="500" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
    <dispatcher-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="500" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
    <reconnect count="15" frequency="5000" blocking="true"/>
</jms:activemq-connector>


   
<jms:activemq-connector name="com.test.esb.interface2.jmsConnector" 
      username="${domain.amq.user.id}" password="${domain.amq.user.password}" 
      connectionFactory-ref="pooledConnectionFactory"
      validateConnections="true" 
      numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="16"
      persistentDelivery="false" 
      doc:name="AMQ Connector for interface2 Interface" 
      specification="1.1">
 <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="500" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT" threadWaitTimeout="30000"/>
 <dispatcher-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="500" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
 <reconnect count="15" frequency="5000" blocking="true"/>
</jms:activemq-connector>

   
<jms:activemq-connector name="com.test.esb.destination.router.jmsConnector" 
      username="${domain.amq.user.id}" password="${domain.amq.user.password}" 
      connectionFactory-ref="pooledConnectionFactory"
      validateConnections="true" 
      numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="8"
      persistentDelivery="false" 
      doc:name="AMQ Connector for DestinationRouter" 
      specification="1.1">
 <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="500" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
 <dispatcher-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="500" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT"/>
 <reconnect count="15" frequency="5000" blocking="true"/>
</jms:activemq-connector>

   
<jms:activemq-connector name="com.test.esb.dlq.jmsConnector" 
      username="${domain.amq.user.id}" password="${domain.amq.user.password}" 
      connectionFactory-ref="pooledConnectionFactory"
      validateConnections="true" 
      numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers="16"
      persistentDelivery="false" 
      doc:name="AMQ Connector for Dead Letter Queue" 
      specification="1.1">
 <receiver-threading-profile maxThreadsActive="500" poolExhaustedAction="WAIT" threadWaitTimeout="30000"/>
 <reconnect count="15" frequency="5000" blocking="true"/>
</jms:activemq-connector>
```

mule-spring config---->

```html
<spring:bean id="domainRedeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
  <spring:property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="5" />
  <spring:property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="500" />
  <spring:property name="maximumRedeliveryDelay" value="10000" />
  <spring:property name="useExponentialBackOff" value="false" />
  <spring:property name="backOffMultiplier" value="3" />
 </spring:bean>
 
 
 

 
 <!-- ActiveMQ Connection factory -->
 <spring:bean id="domainConnectionFactory"
  class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" lazy-init="true">
  <spring:property name="brokerURL"
   value="tcp://192.0.0.0:61616?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=1" />
  <spring:property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="domainRedeliveryPolicy" />
 </spring:bean>
 
 
  <!-- amqExceptionConnectionFactory Connection factory -->
 <spring:bean id="amqExceptionConnectionFactory"
  class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" lazy-init="true">
  <spring:property name="brokerURL"
   value="failover:(${domain.amq.failover.url}?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=50)" />
  <spring:property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="domainRedeliveryPolicy" />
 </spring:bean>
 
 
 <spring:bean id="pooledConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.jms.pool.PooledConnectionFactory" >
  <spring:property name="connectionFactory" ref="domainConnectionFactory"/>
         <spring:property name="maxConnections" value="10000" />
         <spring:property name="maximumActiveSessionPerConnection" value="10000" />
     </spring:bean>

 <spring:bean id="trackTraceRedeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
  <spring:property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="5" />
  <spring:property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="500" />
  <spring:property name="maximumRedeliveryDelay" value="10000" />
  <spring:property name="useExponentialBackOff" value="false" />
  <spring:property name="backOffMultiplier" value="3" />
 </spring:bean>


 <spring:bean id="trackTraceConnectionFactory"
  class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" lazy-init="true">
  <spring:property name="brokerURL"
  value="failover:(${domain.amq.failover.url})" />
   <!-- value="tcp://${domain.amq.host}:${domain.amq.port}" /> -->
   
  <spring:property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="trackTraceRedeliveryPolicy" />
 </spring:bean>

 

 <spring:bean id="interface2ConnectionFactory"
  class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" lazy-init="true">
  <spring:property name="brokerURL"
  value="tcp://192.0.0.0:61616?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=1" />
   <!-- value="tcp://${domain.amq.host}:${domain.amq.port}" /> -->
  <spring:property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="interface2RedeliveryPolicy" />
 </spring:bean>

 <spring:bean id="interface2RedeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
  <spring:property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="5" />
  <spring:property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="500" />
  <spring:property name="maximumRedeliveryDelay" value="10000" />
  <spring:property name="useExponentialBackOff" value="false" />
  <spring:property name="backOffMultiplier" value="3" />
 </spring:bean>

 <!-- ********************* Destination Router Configurations ******************************** -->
 <!-- ActiveMQ Connection factory for destination Router -->
 <spring:bean id="destinationRouterConnectionFactory"
  class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" lazy-init="true">
  <spring:property name="brokerURL"
  value="tcp://192.0.0.0:61616?jms.prefetchPolicy.all=1" />
   <!-- value="tcp://${domain.amq.host}:${domain.amq.port}" /> -->
  <spring:property name="redeliveryPolicy"
   ref="destinationRouterRedeliveryPolicy" />
 </spring:bean>

 <spring:bean id="destinationRouterRedeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
  <spring:property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="5" />
  <spring:property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="500" />
  <spring:property name="maximumRedeliveryDelay" value="10000" />
  <spring:property name="useExponentialBackOff" value="false" />
  <spring:property name="backOffMultiplier" value="3" />
 </spring:bean>

 <!-- ********************* Dead Letter Queue (DLQ) Configurations ******************************** -->
 <!-- ActiveMQ Connection factory for Dead Letter Queue -->
 <spring:bean id="dlqConnectionFactory"
  class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory" lazy-init="true">
  <spring:property name="brokerURL"
  value="failover:(${domain.amq.failover.url})" />
   
  <spring:property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="dlqRedeliveryPolicy" />
 </spring:bean>

 <spring:bean id="dlqRedeliveryPolicy" class="org.apache.activemq.RedeliveryPolicy">
  <spring:property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="5" />
  <spring:property name="initialRedeliveryDelay" value="500" />
  <spring:property name="maximumRedeliveryDelay" value="10000" />
  <spring:property name="useExponentialBackOff" value="false" />
  <spring:property name="backOffMultiplier" value="3" />
 </spring:bean>
```

Comment: There may be a few things to add to the activemq.xml-- what is your activemq.xml configuration?

Comment: @MattPavlovich Please find my edits to me question above with activemq.xml details

Comment: Great, most of what you have there uses the defaults which should easily blow by your target performance numbers. You cantry adding a queuePretch="128" and optimizedDispatch="true", but I suspect the issue is client connection factory our Mule inefficencies.  Many frameworks like Spring JMSTemplate have high latency which make the appearance of slow consuming. I'd write a quick JMS consumer to confirm that its not the broker (which I suspect its not the broker).

Comment: Can you post the connection factory settings and any mule config on the JMS endpoint?

Comment: @MattPavlovich, I have updated for your reference. Your expertise may help

Comment: Also did you mean queuePrefetch at mule consumer URI side?

Comment: @MattPavlovich Any idea?

Comment: prefetch=1 provides strong ordering and reliability setup at the expense of higher latency (which would appear to be slow consuming). You probably want to increase that b/w 128 and 1024 and apply @aled's notes about thread management.

Comment: When I have 10 messages per second, 128 looks too high as only one consumer will be actively picking. Isnt  it?

Comment: 10 msg/s is very low traffic. Are the messages very large (> 1MB)? or the processing take a long time? (> 100ms)?  It begs the question if multiple threads are needed for throughput or high-availability instead

Answer (score 0):

`numberOfConsumers` is the atribute that determines the number of client threads if the endpoing is using transactions. If the endpoint is in a transaction then you need to use `numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers` instead.

You should really remove the `<dispatcher-threading-profile>` and `<receiver-threading-profile>` configurations. 500 threads per JMS configuration is a lot for your system, it is a lot of resources if they are created, and will not help for this use case at all. You should set these values only because of some real reason.

Try to capture a thread dump when the processing is slow to analyze what are the threads doing. That should point to the root cause.

Reference: https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/JMS-Usage-of-numberOfConsumers-and-numberOfConcurrentTransactedReceivers

Comment: Is there a possibility that mule can identify if it is numberofconsumers or numberoftransactedrecievers? Because I see even if I specify numberofconsumers it shows numberoftransactedrecievers in mule domain log-